# Bootstrap example Carousel code not switching slides

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I've been researching for over an hour and I cannot get this example code from the Bootstrap website for a Carousel working... the only thing I changed are the image sources. What am I doing wrong? If it helps, this will be in a component in an Angular project.

```html
<div id="ourCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#ourCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#ourCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#ourCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#ourCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#ourCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

I know that Bootstrap is loading because the first image is showing along with the controls and indicators are there -- the only thing is that they're not responsive.

I put the below code in the main app component, which from there the carousel component is called.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I also tried adding this before and after the code above...

```html
<script>
  $("#ourCarousel").carousel();
</script>
```

I feel like I've done everything imaginable to get it to work, am I missing any important steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is putting the above code (waiting for the document to be ready) and moving the imports of Bootstrap from the module with the carousel to index.html. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried, but it doesn't seem to be a problem. Guess javascript cannot select html.
OR

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   wait for the document to load.
   $("#ourCarousel").carousel()
})
```

```js
$("#ourCarousel").carousel()
```

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <div id="ourCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#ourCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#ourCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#ourCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1525160354320-d8e92641c563?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=d46c460396a4572221a1aa45cf67fc6b&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1834&q=80" alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1525160354320-d8e92641c563?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=d46c460396a4572221a1aa45cf67fc6b&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1834&q=80" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1525160354320-d8e92641c563?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=d46c460396a4572221a1aa45cf67fc6b&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1834&q=80" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
      </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#ourCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#ourCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
```